Multi-step CNN-LSTM Encoder Decoder Model is not fitting well on peak values
I am trying to predict 4 values concurrently for next 24 hours
n_lookback = 48  
n_forecast = 24 

I am breaking the sequences like this:
for i in range(n_lookback, len(y) - n_forecast + 1):

    X.append(y[i - n_lookback: i, 0:df[cols].shape[1]])
    Y.append(y[i: i + n_forecast, 0:df[cols].shape[1]])

Below is the architecture of my model
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)


X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, n_lookback, 4)
# fit the model
model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape= (None, n_lookback, 4))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(2)))
model.add(Flatten())

# LSTM layers
model.add(RepeatVector(n_forecast))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4)))

But it not learning peak. It just overshoots above peak.

Orange line is prediction line
It performs exceptionally well, when I did it in univariate prediction but performs poor in multivariate prediction.
Kindly help me in this regard.
